# How can springboot app both run in main method and run in tomcat with the same configuration as below?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is the whole pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.example.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>             

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The Application class should be like this

Application.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    /**
     * Used when run as JAR
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody String hello(){
        return "hello world!";
    }

    /**
     * Used when run as WAR
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

The whole project is as you can see as above.However,the main method can not run if I set the scope

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

to provided.But if I remove the scope,the main method can run normally.The question is what should I do to run the main method without removing the scope.

Comment: its the `@controller` annotation that you need to study first

Comment: spring-boot-maven-plugin will package `provided` scoped dependencies into `WEB-INF/lib-provided`, the location will not been picked by container when you deploy it as a .WAR. You should post the exception stack trace on how __"the main method can not run"__ for others to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In maven, when you omit the `scope` it defaults to `compile`.
- When you are running outside a servlet container (i.e as a java
  application) you need to provide the `scope` of `compile` (or remove scope as `compile` is the default). This is done so that these jars are added as dependency.
- When you run within a servlet container (tomcat or jetty), then the `scope` could be set as `provided` as these jars are provided at runtime by the servlet container and should not be included within the packaged application.

Now, in order to solve the problem at hand you could use maven profiles. When executing maven tasks you could activate the profile by using the `-P` switch.

Comment: @Wulh Please accept the answer if it has helped you!!